# Android stuidio environment error

Tags: android, multithreading

I build my project in my IDE Android studio 3.0.1 I meet a error says

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

- What went wrong:

  Execution failed for task

  ':PdfViewerTestApp:transformDexWithInstantRunSlicesApkForDebug'.

  > java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService$QueueingFuture@4ceeee6f rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@578a6ff1[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]

But I use other's IDE and build the same project it can build successfully, so I think it matters about the environemnt setting of my IDE, maybe some plugins, does anyone meet the same or similar case?

Comment: Try to delete your 'Build' folder. Then File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart in Android Studio

Comment: Tried but still the issue appears